# How to create extra column to user table after login through facebook rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

if the current user is new,I need to add category after login through facebook.(category contains list of items)

User Model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :email, :name, :uid, :provider
validates_presence_of :name, :uid
validates_uniqueness_of :uid

has_many :votes 

def self.from_omniauth(auth)
  where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_initialize.tap do |user|

    user.provider = auth.provider
    user.uid = auth.uid
    user.name = auth.info.name          
    user.save!
  end
end
```

Users Controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
respond_to :html, :json

def create   
  @user = User.from_omniauth(env["omniauth.auth"])    
  session[:user_id] = @user.id
  redirect_to browsing_url
 end
end
```

application controller

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

protect_from_forgery with: :null_session   

private  

def current_user
@current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id])if session[:user_id]
end

helper_method :current_user
end
```

If the current user is an existing user it should redirect to browsing_url. It is working fine, but my question is how to create a category if the current user is a new user.

Comment: Generally speaking, changing your actual **schema** in response to user actions is a **bad idea**.  You should refactor your app so that you're creating a record in an existing table, not creating a whole new column.

Comment: Do you actually **want** to add a category column to a table?  or do you just mean that you want to create a Category record, or set a user's `category_id`, rather than change the table schema?

Comment: @MaxWilliams I need to create a category record if the current user is new

Comment: Can you please then edit your question to change the title, and improve the wording?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to redirect user after login, based on conditions whether the logged in user is new user. You can have a `attr_accessor` in `User` model and based on that you can redirect in controller. like below code.

In your `User` model -

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :new_user   

end
```

You can assign flag  to `attr_accessor` in ominiauth method of `User` model like -

```
class User

    def self.from_omniauth(auth)
      where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_initialize.tap do |user|

      user.provider = auth.provider
      user.uid = auth.uid
      user.name = auth.info.name          
      user.new_user = user.new_record?
      user.save!
    end
  end
```

In users controller,

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html, :json

  def create   
    @user = User.from_omniauth(env["omniauth.auth"])    
    session[:user_id] = @user.id
    if @user.new_user
      redirect_to 'other_path'
    else
      redirect_to browsing_url
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Is this actually what the poster wants to do?  I think the title may be misleading and they actually just want to create a Category record.

Comment: sorry I didn't mean it, actually if the current user is new I have to create a category which has list of items.

Comment: Then it should be a separate table instead, like @MaxWilliams says. You can generate a `Category` model with `name` field.

Comment: @VishnuAtrai yep, you are right, I am having the category model. but my question is when the user login through facebook, `from_omniauth` is fetching the details of the user from facebook, after that I need to check if the current user is new, if yes he have to insert a category to the table otherwise he should redirect to the browsing_url. sorry for my english, do u understand what is my query?

Comment: @saravana I added the condition in code, you can put one condition `if user.new_record?`

Comment: @VishnuAtrai categories table contains list of item such as actor, singer, director,producer, musician